# JNLP Main Class argument based on OS

Tags: java, parameters, runtime, jnlp

I want to pass an argument to the main class ran via Java Webstart. The only way I've been able to do this is using  within the application-desc element. Sadly this requires one jnlp file for each OS/Architecture combination.

Is there a way to do the same from the resource element? I would need to use different arguments depending on the architecture of the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value can be defined as a `property` in the `resources` element.  See [JNLP File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) for details.